# Unable to connect to apache from the web

Tags: iptables, httpd, httpd.conf

I have an apache instance running with vhost configured, here is the httpd.conf:

```
#Listen {the_server_ip}:80
Listen 80
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ErrorLog logs/example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the record in the /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com www.example.com
```

The server is running and listening:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      8756/httpd
```

Here is CURL request from the server:

**[root@localhost example]# curl -I http://example.com/index.html**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2016 11:12:47 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Last-Modified: Tue, 01 Mar 2016 11:12:12 GMT
ETag: "8aaa-5-52cfad64b4dbe"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 5
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Here are my iptables rules for INPUT chain:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 30 packets, 2242 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  195  150K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  185 15126 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
37508  101M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  192 11152 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
   64  3116 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80
```

Here are my iptables rules for the OUTPUT chain:

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 3 packets, 152 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  199  151K ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
16220 3289K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:22
  692 47470 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            8.8.8.8             udp dpt:53
  107  8636 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
14164  603K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80
  430 18880 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443
```

TCPDUMP:

```
[root@localhost iwanttobesysadmin.com]# tcpdump -v port 80 and host {home_ip}
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
3 packets captured
3 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

I am also not able to telnet from my Windows machine on port 80 on the server, but it is ping-able.
I believe that there is some restriction in the INPUT chain firewall rules.

Comment: What telnet command are you using and message do you get from telnet ?

Comment: I am running the:
**telnet {the_server_ip} 80**

`The message:
Connecting To {the_server_ip}...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed`

Comment: It could be restriction in your OUTPUT chain too

Comment: Updated the case with OUTPUT chain as well.

Comment: I have noticed that the server listens on :::80 which is localhost for IPv6?
Any idea how to switch to listen on all interfaces, but for IPv4 port 80?

Comment: Try 'tcpdump port 80 and host {your_windows_machine_ip}' on the server and then use telnet and watch if your packets going in and out.

Comment: Updated the case with tcpdump

Comment: Can you verify with tcpdump that your server is indeed reachable on other TCP ports (eg. ssh)?

Comment: I am PuTTY-ing from my Windows PC to the server on port 22, so it is reachable I believe

Comment: If you are hosting your server in the cloud you probably also need to check external firewall rules like Amazon Security Groups

Comment: @GeorgiTsvetanovTsenov `:::80` is *all ipv6 interfaces on port 80*, and often implies all ipv4 interfaces as well.  `::1:80` is *localhost ipv6 only*.

Comment: Could you add a rule to your output chain as follows: `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`, and report back?

Comment: It is still better to verify using ssh that you are testing correct interface with tcpdump and you still can connect.

Comment: @MadHatter Thank you m8!
The iptables rule made the connection successful!

Comment: @GeorgiTsvetanovTsenov I have written that up as an answer, so you can accept it, and the question can be put to bed (as it were).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*I believe that there is some restriction in the INPUT chain firewall rules.*"

You believe wrongly.  There is, however, a problem in the `OUTPUT` chain, because although you're letting people in to talk to your web server, you're not letting the responses back out.

You added a stateful output rule, to permit that traffic, with

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

and all now works.

Comment: Absolutely true :)